# can skew be replaced with scale + rotate3d

Tags: matrix, canvas, graphics, linear-algebra

Can skew be represented by scale plus rotate3d when the graphics are changed?
When I make a skew transformation on a picture, if I use an animation, it visually feels like the picture is zoomed and rotated in the 3d direction.

Comment: if you mean 2D skew then that can be done by `scale3d + rotate3d + projection3d` up to some point, however for 3D skew you need 4D ...

Comment: @Spektre Is it possible to think that translation, scaling and rotation are basic deformations and cannot be separated. Skew is a composite deformation, the former is similar to the three primary colors of red, green and blue, while the latter is a combined color

Comment: its exactly the opposite skew is deformation and translation,rotation are not and decompose-able (they do not change geometrical properties like shape,size,area,volume)... What skew does is deform coordiante system so the axises are no longer perpendicular to each ...